# Issues with for loop when switching from radio to checkbox

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields

We have a wordpress site using Twig and advanced custom fields to show a custom post type value on a page. There used to be just one value for the role field and we used radio buttons. We had to switch that to checkboxes because multiple roles need to be selected for some posts.

That went fine but now the for loop that we had in place doesn’t work for posts with multiple roles selected. It still displays posts which have one role selected, however. I’d appreciate any help with this as it’s written in Twig and that’s completely foreign to me! Is there a way to check for both conditions and something different for each? Or is there a way to edit every existing post to update the field so that it will always return an array?

Tried checking with ACF support but they were not familiar with using twig.

This is the .twig page.

```
<section class="section people">
           <div class="row row-17-column">
               <h1 id="team" class="header-large center">Our Team</h1>
               <div class="bio-profiles">
                   {% for team in team %}
                       <bio-profile bio-id="'{{team.ID}}'" :bio-length="{{team.biography|length}}">
                           <img slot="photo" src="{{TimberImage(team.photo).src}}" alt="{{TimberImage(team.photo).caption}}">
                           <h3 slot="name" class="header-small full-width">{{team.first_name}}<br>{{team.last_name}}</h3>
                           <p slot="position" class="profile-position">{{team.job_title}}<br />{{team.company}}</p>
                           <div slot="related" class="related-stories hide-small"></div>
                           <p slot="quote">&ldquo;{{ team.quote }}&rdquo;</p>
                           <p slot="bio">{{ team.biography }}</p>
                       </bio-profile>
                   {% endfor %}
               </div>
           </div>
       </section>
```

Here is the array that needs to be modified to pull in more than one value. They could also have a value for director or advisor along with team. there are 3 total value options.

```
 $team = Timber::get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'person',
                'meta_key' => 'last_name',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query' => [
                    array(
                        'key' => 'role',
                        'value' => 'team'
                    )
                ]
        ));
```

When we switched from radio to checkboxes It still displays posts which have one role selected but if there is more than one, they don't display at all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you query only selects posts with the role `team`, as you added this statically in your code `array('key' => 'role', 'value' => 'team')`

Comment: so could we just add the other two values that could be selected in the array? Or would that only show them if they had all three selected? There will be some that have multiple values and we need them to display if any of the role values are selected, not just team. Does that make sense? Would this work?    `'value' => ('team' , 'director', 'advisor')`

Answer (score 0):

As has been highlighted, you're doing a query to bring back the role team as opposed to all the roles you've now added. Changing your loop to the following should be sufficient, simply update the `$roles` array with the value of each of your roles:

```
$roles = array('team', 'director', 'advisor');
$team = Timber::get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'person',
            'meta_key' => 'last_name',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => [
                array(
                    'key' => 'role',
                    'value' => $roles,
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                )
            ]
    )
);
```

Comment: great, I will try that and see if that does it. Thank you for replying.

Comment: so it's pulling in all of the post types with those values, not if it has one or two of them. Some will have only 2 of the three selected. Some just one.

Comment: It's now pulling in all of the post types with those values, not if it has one or two of them. Some will have only 2 of the three selected in the checkboxes within ACF. Some just one. Is there a way to pull them in if any of them or combination of them is selected? There is another section on the page that just pulls in the Advisors and one that just pulls the Directors. The Team section is the only one where there may be a post type that has both Team and Director selected and need to be shown on both sections. Right now anyone that has more than one checkbox selected isn't showing anywhere.

Comment: try adding the compare section I just added, it'll check the stored field array to see if there is any of the values mention in the query present

Comment: unfortunately, that had no effect. I think we will try a work-around so we can get it completed. Thank you so much for your support!